# Dictionary values keep changing while recursing despite not adding anything to the dictionary

Tags: python

Here is my code for the coin change problem:

```pt
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int, sequence = []) -> int:
        
        def coinChangeInner(self, coins: List[int], amount: int, sequence, memo) -> int:
            if amount < 0:
                return -1
            if amount in memo:
                print(memo)
                return memo[amount]
            if amount < min(coins):
                return -1
            
            shortest_sequence = None

            for coin in coins:
                answer = coinChangeInner(self, coins, amount-coin, sequence, memo)
                
                if answer != -1:
                    answer.append(coin)
                    sequence = answer
                    if (shortest_sequence == None) or (len(sequence) < len(shortest_sequence)):
                        shortest_sequence = sequence
            
            return shortest_sequence
        
        sequence = []
        memo1 = {}
        memo1[0] = []
        ans = coinChangeInner(self, coins, amount, sequence, memo1)
        print(ans)
        if ans == -1 or ans == None:
            return -1
        else:
            return len(ans)
```

Now in this code, I'm not making any modifications to `memo` within the `coinChangeInner()` body itself. I just initialize memo outside it (in `coinChange()`) and pass it in, with no further changes. However, here is the result of `print(memo)` on line 8:

```
{0: [1, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}
{0: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1]}
.....
```

This just keeps exploding like this (my input was `[1,2,5], 11`). What I'm unable to understand is why extra values keep getting to the value for the key `memo[0]`.

Could someone point it out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding what your code is supposed to do, but I think I can at least explain how all these values are getting into memo[0].

The issue with things like this is because lists are mutable, so inputing a list into a function will not create a new instance of the list.

Basically in line 9, you `return memo[amount]`.
Line 16 `answer = coinChangeInner(self, coins, amount-coin, sequence, memo)`, now answer is the mutable list stored at memo[0].
Line 19 `answer.append(coin)`, now you are appending a coin to the mutable list stored at memo[0].

I'm really not sure if this is the answer you were looking for, or if what I have mentioned is done intentionally. But also the recursion is very difficult to follow because each time you call coinChangeInner, it will call itself again three more times, one for each coin. As you can see this will exponentially grow very fast, so memo[0] is going to get very large.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that `answer.append(coin)` would change `memo[0]`. 
I'm trying to find all possible ways of reaching the amount with the coins. And yes, it will grow exponentially fast, I was trying to memoize it.